# PHP Startup: Can not find module php_pdo

Tags: php, pdo

I am running XAMPP v.1.8.3, on Windows 7, which shipped with PHP version 5.5.6. I manually downloaded PHP version 5.6.1 and put it in `xampp/php`. The old folder `php` I renamed to `php_5.5.6`. I enabled `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` in `php.ini` ( which was initially named `php.ini-development`, had to rename to `php.ini` ) and started getting this error when starting apache

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\php_pdo_mysql.dll' -
>   The specified module could not be found.

Then I located the extension `dll` and it was in `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_mysql.dll`, so I moved it to `C:\xampp\php\php_pdo_mysql.dll` but the error remains. Why isn't it finding the driver?

What is not making sense for me is that on my older version (5.5.6) the extension was also in the `ext` folder and not in the main `php` folder.

Comment: Did you restart your webserver?

Comment: @PeeHaa numerous times, in desperate attempts the error would go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was rather simple, as suggested [here](http://www.somacon.com/p447.php) my `extension_dir` was not correct. Which doesn't explain why moving the file to the actual `extension_dir` would still produce this error.